# Easyadmin bundle + sf 4 : can't display a field in form

Tags: symfony, bundle, symfony4, r-sf, easyadmin

I'm trying to set up my product creation page, and configure the form.
I have 2 entities : Product, and ProductTranslates

**Database**:

product
[image]

product_translate
[image]

There is a foreign key on product_id_id (don't know why i have twice "id"...)

I would like to use some product_translates fields, inside my product.yaml (see below)

For example, i'd like in my form, to add the "description".
Do you know how i can do that please ? I can easily use the "product" properties, but don't know how to do with the product_translate, in the yaml file.

Thank you very much !!!

```
easy_admin:
  entities:
    # the configuration of this entity is very verbose because it's used as
    # an example to show all the configuration options available for entities
    # check out the configuration of the other entities to see how concise
    # can be the configuration of your backend
    Product:
      class: App\Entity\Product
      label: 'Produits'
      list:
        ...
      form:
        title: 'Créer un produit'
        fields:
          - { property: 'univers', label: 'univers' }
          - { property: 'product_code', label: 'Référence', type: 'number' }
          - { property: 'category_id', label: 'Catégorie', type: 'easyadmin_autocomplete', type_options: { class: 'App\Entity\Product' } }
          - { property: 'is_cocktail', label: 'Est-ce un cocktail ?', type: 'checkbox' }
          - { property: 'is_active', label: 'Voulez vous le publier ?', type: 'checkbox' }
          - { property: 'alcohol_volume', label: 'Degré d''alcool', type: 'number' }
          - { property: 'created_at', label: 'Date de création', type: 'datetime' }
          - { property: 'photo', type: 'file', label: 'Uploader une photo', help: 'Sélectionner le fichier' }
      edit:
        ...
```

Final result :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can nest another form type in easy admin(if the relation is @OneToOne), or add a collection of the ProductTranslate(if the relation is @ManyToOne),
First variant:

```
fields:
          - { property: 'univers', label: 'univers' }
          - { property: 'product_code', label: 'Référence', type: 'number' }
          - { property: 'category_id', label: 'Catégorie', type: 'easyadmin_autocomplete', type_options: { class: 'App\Entity\Product' } }
          - { property: 'is_cocktail', label: 'Est-ce un cocktail ?', type: 'checkbox' }
          - { property: 'is_active', label: 'Voulez vous le publier ?', type: 'checkbox' }
          - { property: 'alcohol_volume', label: 'Degré d''alcool', type: 'number' }
          - { property: 'created_at', label: 'Date de création', type: 'datetime' }
          - { property: 'photo', type: 'file', label: 'Uploader une photo', help: 'Sélectionner le fichier' }
          - { property: 'productTranslate', label: 'Description', type: ProductTranslateType }
```

Second variant

```
fields:
          - { property: 'univers', label: 'univers' }
          - { property: 'product_code', label: 'Référence', type: 'number' }
          - { property: 'category_id', label: 'Catégorie', type: 'easyadmin_autocomplete', type_options: { class: 'App\Entity\Product' } }
          - { property: 'is_cocktail', label: 'Est-ce un cocktail ?', type: 'checkbox' }
          - { property: 'is_active', label: 'Voulez vous le publier ?', type: 'checkbox' }
          - { property: 'alcohol_volume', label: 'Degré d''alcool', type: 'number' }
          - { property: 'created_at', label: 'Date de création', type: 'datetime' }
          - { property: 'photo', type: 'file', label: 'Uploader une photo', help: 'Sélectionner le fichier' }
          - { property: 'productTranslates', label: 'Product translates', type: collection, type_options: { entry_type: ProductTranslateType }
```

Of course you need to provide full path(namespace + class) to the custom form type

Comment: thank you for your help, i'll explore that solution !